# How to add a jest spy in nest.js custom service provider that was loaded dynamically using useClass approach?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nestjs

I'm trying to write a unit test that checks if a method from a specific service was called from a controller using jest `spyOn` with `toHaveBeenCalled`.

I created the provider in a way it determines the class dynamically, inspired by [this approach from official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#class-providers-useclass):

```js
const ExampleProvider = (ambient: string) => {
  return {
    provide: 'ExampleService',
    useClass:
      ambient == 'production' ? ProductionService : DevelopmentService,
  }
};
```

In the controller, I inject the provider into constructor in this way:

```js
@Inject('ExampleService') private exampleService: DevelopmentService | ProductionService
```

In the tests, I defined the test module and tried to load the service as another ones in `beforeEach` method:

```js
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [MyController],
      imports: [ ... module imports ],
      providers: [
        AnotherService,
        ExampleProvider("development") // <- this will load DevelopmentFlowService
      ],
    }).compile();

    anotherService = module.get<AnotherService>(AnotherService);
    exampleService = module.get('ExampleService');
    controller = module.get<MyController>(MyController);
  });
```

```js
  it('... test description', async () => {
    const spy1 = jest.spyOn(anotherService, 'method').mockImplementation(() => ...); // this works

    const spy2 = jest.spyOn(exampleService, 'method').mockImplementation(() => ...); // this not works

    await controller.method(...); // method that calls methods from both spy services

    expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this works
    expect(spy2).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this not works
  });
```

I logged the content of controller's `exampleService` after apply `spyOn` method and its content does not change. It looks like the instance of `exampleService` I loaded from Test module is not the same instance that is injected in controller.

As workaround, I created a method `getExampleService` that returns the instance of `exampleService` that is really used by controller:

```js
const spy2 = jest.spyOn(controller.getExampleService(), 'method').mockImplementation(() => ...); // now this works
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I load the `exampleService` instance used by controller without using that kind of workaround?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/testing#testing-request-scoped-instances

Comment: Thanks for the link. I tried to load only the exampleService, but it didn't work. I think the approach may be not work because I'm not using a request-scoped instance but a custom provider that is instantiated dynamically on default scope. Or I should load all the services with that approach on the link?